# Maximum limit for data included in a transaction?

Tags: eosio-code, evm, geth

I am really new to EOS.IO. I need to send transactions to a private Blockchain and I am having some trouble with geth, so I was wondering if EOS could be a solution. I know by geth source code it is limited to `128 KB: txMaxSize = 4 * txSlotSize // 128KB` -> tx_pool.go file: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go. Because of these limit i am getting `err: overaized data` in geth when trying to make a transaction with big data in it (store a string of 200000 characters). Do you guys know if EOS does limit the amount of data sent in a transaction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you currently can just use geth to send transactions to leap-based blockchains. The EVM and the API's needed are not live yet and still under development or in testing. Probably specific testnets like kylin already provide parts of the functionallity but I would check first if there's support for geth available.